# What is the difference between semantic in nlp and semantic in ontology?

Tags: nlp, semantic-web, ontology

What is the difference between 'semantic' in nlp and 'semantic' in ontology accessed through an api such as jena??

Comment: Non-programming terminology isn't really on-topic for Stack Overflow.  I hesitate to offer either http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ -- certainly check their charters before posting anything there.

Comment: This is remarkably vague.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs to another site linguistics or data science stackexchange

Comment: Semantics is meaning. NLP is a computational processing of language (meaning (semantics, discourse, pragmatics, etc.), sound (phonetics, phonology, prosody, etc.) and grammar ( syntax, morphology, etc. ). Ontology is a (graph-based) structured manner of constructing meaning. Recommended read: https://books.google.de/books?id=fZmj5UNK8AQC&redir_esc=y and http://www.amazon.com/Oxford-Handbook-Computational-Linguistics-Handbooks/dp/019927634X and computationally www.nltk.org/book/

Comment: @alvas I know the difference between NLP and Ontology :). I wanted to distinguish b/w the concept of 'semantics' in both. I couldn't find something really helpful; that's why I asked. Some people are unable to differentiate b/w 'semantic' in nlp and 'semantic' in semantic web, & therefore, I hoped some ontologist might be able to make the distinction. Thanks for the recommended reads though; I'll definitely try to go through these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can find from a quick search, semantics is

> the branch of linguistics and logic concerned with meaning. The two main areas are logical semantics, concerned with matters such as sense and reference and presupposition and implication, and lexical semantics, concerned with the analysis of word meanings and relations between them.

This is the correct definition for NLP semantics. For Semantic Web, semantics is specifically the semantics of logical languages defined for the Semantic Web, i.e., RDF, RDFS, OWL (1 and 2). The main difference between the semantics of these languages and that of other languages (logical and not) is the restrictions that are applied to RDF/S and OWL (1/2) DL to make them machine understandable; this means that, in these languages, all implications can be made explicit in finite time.

You can find a lot of material on RDFS and OWL on the W3C pages:

http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/